# Explain Reciprocal Velocity Objects to me

Tags: collision-detection, rts, collision-avoidance

*This is follow-up on this question ([Unit collision avoidance for RTS](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136197))*

I'm developing an RTS. I'm having difficulty with collision detection... I looked up RVO and it seems like the correct solution, but I'm having difficulty understanding how it exactly works. Can someone explain the math behind RVO in comprehensible terms?

I tried compiling the RVO sample program but it won't compile in the latest version of Visual Studio. I'm stumped.

Comment: How are you with linear algebra?

Comment: Not very good... I just remember high school math.